# react-native axios resolve callback function not executed

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, xmlhttprequest, axios

I want to set a callback function after making a post request with axios.
this code works.

```
onButtonPress(){
this.setState({ status: null, loading: true });

axios.post(url, {
    'email': this.state.email,
    'password': this.state.password
})
.then(response => {
  this.setState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
    status: 'Authentication Successful',
    loading: false
  })
})
.catch(this.onLoginFail.bind(this))
}
```

But when assign the callback to a separate function like this, the function does not resolve the promise

```
onButtonPress(){
this.setState({ status: null, loading: true });

axios.post(url, {
    'email': this.state.email,
    'password': this.state.password
})
.then(response => {
  this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this)
})
.catch(this.onLoginFail.bind(this))
}

onLoginSuccess(){
  this.setState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
    status: 'Authentication Successful',
    loading: false
  })
}
```

How would i resolve the promise like the second block of code?

Comment: why u call this.onLoginSuccess.'bind(this)' why not just this.onLoginSuccess()??

Comment: because im passing the onButtoPress() method to a child component, so i need to bind the execution context to the current execution context. If im not mistaken

Comment: did u try just calling this.onLoginSuccess()??

because callbacks works in same context (means execution context = binding context)

Comment: orr if its necessary to pass ''this'' in to onLoginSuccess then receive in as a variable in onLoginSuccess(context){context..setState({.....});}

Comment: actually calling just this.onLoginSuccess() worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do in your second example is you are just binding the function to this instance, but not making a call. Instead of binding a function to this instance inside a function is a bad practice. It will bind as many time the function triggers, instead do this inside constructor which executes one time. Then pass the function to the axios resolve and reject (which is then and catch) as a callback.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onLoginSuccess=this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this);
    this.onLoginFail=this.onLoginFail.bind(this);
    this.onButtonPress=this.onButtonPress.bind(this);
} 

onButtonPress(){
     this.setState({ status: null, loading: true }, ()=> {
         axios.post(url, {
             'email': this.state.email,
             'password': this.state.password
         })
         .then(this.onLoginSuccess)
         .catch(this.onLoginFail);
     });
}

onLoginSuccess(){
    this.setState({
        email: '',
        password: '',
        status: 'Authentication Successful',
        loading: false
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case , it's working fine

```
  axios.post(Urls.UploadImage, bodyFormData, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      Authorization: "Bearer Token" 
    }
  })
  .then((response) => this.onUploadSuccess(response))
  .catch((error) => this.onUploadError(error));


 onUploadSuccess(response){
 }

 onUploadError(error){
 }
```